# Trace API-calls on iOS

Tags: ios, trace

I have an app on my phone that is communication with an API.
This API is not fully documented, and some data displayed in the app, I don't know how to reach.

What I wonder is if it's possible in some kind of way to trace what API calls the app is doing?

It's an app for iPhone.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If by "an API" you mean a Web API and thus you want to see which web calls the application makes you can set up a proxy server between the iPhone and the internet and inspect the calls it makes.

See for example [Charles Proxy from an iPhone](http://www.charlesproxy.com/documentation/faqs/using-charles-from-an-iphone/).